# Kivy: Change RstDocument Header Font

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Kivy 1.10.0

Python 3.6

I would like to change the header font-size, color, etc. when using RstDocuments. The default difference between the headers is very small (only a small font-size change), as seen below.

[image]

I've looked through some of the code but I'm not a very experienced Python programmer and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **base_font_size**:

From the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html):

```
base_font_size - Added in 1.8.0
Font size for the biggest title, 31 by default. All other font sizes are 
derived from this.
```

for changing the colors/style of each header/element see:

```
colors Added in 1.1.0
Dictionary of all the colors used in the RST rendering.

Warning
This dictionary is needs special handling. You also need to call RstDocument.render() if you change them after loading. colors is a DictProperty.

 underline_color Added in 1.1.0
 underline color of the titles, expressed in html color notation
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure this is really what I'm looking for. I'm looking to make changes to specific header markup rendering. So for example, when I use header 3 in my example above, I want the text to be black, smaller, and with no underline. I'd like a way to tap into the code (by intercepting the default output, not by changing core code) and change the header display to whatever I want.